# No funciona boton creado dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Tengo este codigo en un archivo .js, que al cargar la pagina lista os clientes, en cada fila de la tabla hay un editar, un baja y un alta.

como veran tengo un codigo en el evento click pero no responde con nada:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    listar();
    $("#nombre").keyup(function() {
            
        nombreBusqueda=$("#nombre").val();
        filtrar(nombreBusqueda);
    }
);
$('input[name=baja]').click(function(){
   
       var id=$(this).attr('id');
     
        accion='baja';
           $.ajax({

   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/cliente/includes/editarCliente.php",
            data: {"accion":accion,"id":id}, 
           

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           success: function(data){
                alert("Baja exitosa");
                href="modules/cliente/edicionCliente.php"
           }
           
        
});
   
      });
      $('input[name=alta]').click(function(){
   
       var id=$(this).attr('id');
     
        accion='alta';
           $.ajax({

   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/cliente/includes/editarCliente.php",
            data: {"accion":accion,"id":id}, 
           

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           success: function(data){
                alert("Alta exitosa");
                href="modules/cliente/edicionCliente.php"
           }
           
        
});
   
      });
$("#editar").click(function(){
    
    alert("dd");

  var accion="obtener";

        
        $.ajax({

   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/cliente/includes/editarCliente.php",
            data: {"accion":accion,"id":id}, 
             dataType:"json",

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           success: function(data){
        
            $("#Nombre").val(data[0].nombre);
            $("#CUIT").val(data[0].CUIT);
            $("#Fijo").val(data[0].telfijo);
            $("#Celular").val(data[0].celular);
            $("#domicilio").val(data[0].direccion);
           }
           
        });   
        });
$("#guardar").click(function(){
    var CUIT;
    var fijo;
    var celular;
    var domicilio;
   var accion="guardar";
   var nombre=$("#Nombre").val();
   if ($("#CUIT").val()==""){
    CUIT=0;
   }else{
     CUIT=$("#CUIT").val();
   }
   if ($("#Fijo").val()==""){
    fijo=0;
   }else{
     fijo=$("#Fijo").val();
   }
   if ($("#Celular").val()==""){
    celular=0;
   }else{
     celular=$("#Celular").val();
   }
   if ($("#Celular").val()==""){
    domicilio=0;
   }else{
     domicilio=$("#domicilio").val();
   }
  
 
   $.ajax({

   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/cliente/includes/editarCliente.php",
            data: {"accion":accion,"id":id,"nombre":nombre,"CUIT":CUIT,"fijo":fijo,"cel":celular,"domicilio":domicilio}, 
           

            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           success: function(data){
                alert("Actualizacion exitosa");
                href="modules/cliente/edicionCliente.php"
           }
           
        
});

        
 
  });

    
  
      });
      function filtrar(dato){
        var filtrado=[];
        var existe;
    for(var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    if (content[i].nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(dato.toLowerCase())!=-1) {
        filtrado.push(content[i]);
        
       
    }
}
     if (filtrado.length>0) {
        
      $("#clientes tbody").empty();
        
              for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
          
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].CUIT + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].celular + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].direccion + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].deduda + "</td>" +
                     "<td>"+
          "<a class='btn btn-warning' href='index.php?controller=cliente&action=editar&id="+filtrado[i].idcliente+"'>Editar</a>"+
            "<input type='button' id="+filtrado[i].idcliente+" value='Baja' name='baja' class='btn btn-danger'/>"+
        "<input type='button' id="+filtrado[i].idcliente+" value='Alta' name='alta' class='btn btn-primary' /></td>"+
                    "</tr>";                 
        $(newRow).appendTo("#clientes tbody");
    
               
            }
 
  
}};
function listar(){

    accion="listar";
  $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/cliente/includes/editarCliente.php",
            data: { "accion": accion}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(filtrado){
           content=filtrado;
               for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {

                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                 
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].CUIT + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].celular + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].direccion + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].deduda + "</td>" +
                     "<td>"+
         "<a class='btn btn-warning' href='index.php?controller=cliente&action=editar&id="+filtrado[i].idcliente+"'>Editar</a>"+
            "<input type='button' id="+filtrado[i].idcliente+" value='Baja' name='baja' class='btn btn-danger'/>"+
        "<input type='button' id="+filtrado[i].idcliente+" value='Alta' name='alta' class='btn btn-primary' /></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
               $(newRow).appendTo("#clientes tbody");                
        
    
               
            }
         
  

        }  
});
};
```

El filtrado funciona perfecto y si carga los datos obviamente. Es la baja y el alta lo que no funciona alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si los botones estan creados dinamicamente te aconsejaria de utilizar la siguiente estructura:

```
 $("padre").on("click", "input[name=baja]", function() {
     //lo que queres que haga
 }
```

ahora tu boton esta al interno de una tabla, si la tabla tiene algun id o clase usa ese selector en lugar de `$("padre")`, esta estructura se utiliza con los elementos creados dinamicamente.

espero que te sea de ayuda

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que creás los botones después de asignar los eventos click, o sea, cuando hacés el "$('input[name=baja]').click(...." los botones todavía no existen.

Deberías reemplazar esa asignación del click por un evento que sea llamado desde el botón.  Por ejemplo, la función de baja sería algo así:

```
function baja(elem){
       var id=$(elem).attr('id');
       accion='baja';
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../gestionweb/views/modules/cliente/includes/editarCliente.php",
            data: {"accion":accion,"id":id}, 
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
           success: function(data){
                alert("Baja exitosa");
                href="modules/cliente/edicionCliente.php"
           }      
});
```

y cuando creás el botón deberías hacerlo así:

```
...
"<input type='button' onclick='baja(this)' id="+filtrado[i].idcliente+" value='Baja' name='baja' class='btn btn-danger'/>"+
...
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: `onclick="baja(this)" `y la funcion debe ser algo como `function baja(elem){ var id=elem.attr('id'); .....`

Comment: Es verdad, ya lo corrijo

Answer (score 1):

una de las razones por la cual los objetos creados dinámicamente parezcan no responder a los eventos, es que, cuando escribiste esta parte: `$('input[name=baja]').click()` los botones aún no existían, entonces los botones que luego se crearon no tienen "asignado" ese evento.

Lo que puedes hacer es llamar a un elemento que ya esta creado, como el `document`:

```
$(document).on('click','input[name=baja]',function(){
    //  aquí metes el código
});
```

Espero te sirva.